# Bringing one line to front and change to dashed

Tags: r, ggplot2, format, linegraph

I am trying to edit my current code to bring the "ECHO Fit" (see below) line to the front and make it "longdash". All colors and other line formats stay the same.

Extra: I'm actually also trying to get rid of the "size 0.5" from the graph and have x-axis ticks every 12 units (first tick at 12 and last tick at 72)...if anyone can help with that issue as well.

Here is what my dataframe looks like:

```
  gene_id       X12        X14        X16        X18        X20        X22          X24          X26        X28        X30
1     Rep2 0.7736722  0.4895358 -0.1152436 -0.5861007 -0.5185535 -0.4028582 -0.209116905  0.043706646 -0.0558864 -0.3015712
2     Rep3 0.2103065 -0.1527386 -0.4639241 -0.3344614  0.1491652  0.3355411  0.003713116 -0.466451880 -0.4138540  0.2252987
3 ECHO Fit 1.0061474  0.4496992 -0.1188764 -0.5488580 -0.7423424 -0.6742235 -0.390867010  0.009849424  0.4098608  0.7041348
         X32       X34       X36       X38         X40        X42        X44        X46         X48         X50         X52
1 0.06774353 0.5337989 0.7879655 0.9193020 -0.07623785 -0.8137335 -0.5964319 -0.7249979 -0.69457607 -0.32543356 -0.02661936
2 0.61276259 0.6278027 0.7112873 0.5867178 -0.03538973 -0.4893360 -0.5010887 -0.2860915  0.04822184 -0.08333534 -0.43714633
3 0.82685230 0.7644355 0.5534309 0.2654520 -0.01545444 -0.2162454 -0.2928780 -0.2387261 -0.08225048  0.12429807  0.32119703
         X54        X56        X58        X60       X62         X64         X66         X68          X70         X72
1  0.3506349  0.4740629  0.4997113 0.73874098 0.5660296 -0.08397613 -0.23776407  0.14677824 -0.019013891 -0.55853824
2 -0.4050637 -0.2733731 -0.1443974 0.05656335 0.4104595  0.45333028  0.01404726 -0.12725196 -0.000176578  0.07900585
3  0.4577582  0.5046638  0.4593446 0.34374438 0.1958867  0.05813341 -0.03441813 -0.06236729 -0.025399781  0.05970666
```

This is what my graph currently looks like:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
library(tidyverse)
Graph4_Clock <- read.csv("Graph4_Clock.csv")

Graph4_Clock |>
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("X"), names_to = "HPS", values_to = "Zscore")|>
  mutate(HPS = parse_number(HPS))|>
  ggplot(aes(x = HPS, y = Zscore, color = gene_id))+
  geom_point()+
  geom_line(aes(group=gene_id,size=.5,))+
  ggtitle("Clock")+
  scale_color_manual(values = c("black", "orange", "blue"))+
  theme_bw()+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom", axis.text = element_text(size = 20), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20), axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20), axis.title = element_text(size = 20), plot.title = element_text(size = 20), legend.text = element_text(size = 20), legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

Comment: please provide reproducible example

Comment: @yuliaUU, what is not reproducible about it? If you have issues or suggestions, it helps the new users if you are specific with comments like that.

Comment: @Numbahs84, for the future, the sample data is good but just a skosh difficult for some to import. Namely: (1) when frames' columns are wrapped as they are here, it takes manual editing of raw text to get it to a point that we can try to use `read.table` on it; and (2) when any cell contents contain embedded spaces (as in `"ECHO Fit"`), that breaks `read.table`, requiring further manual intervention. Showing the frame output like above is not a problem, but providing a completely unambiguous format (such as the output from `dput(.)` really _really_ helps, makes it easier to answer. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three things:

- To guarantee the z-level (which is "on top" on the plot), one really needs to plot each group of lines separately, where the last plotted is "on top"; we can use `data=~subset(., gene_id=...)` for this, and using two `geom_line` layers.
- I'm moving `size=0.5` out of the `aes(.)` so that it does not create a singleton legend. This brings the lines to the actual width you expect (the literal `0.5`, vice a categorical variable that is the same, `"0.5"`, for all lines).
- Setting `"longdash"` is easy enough by adding `linetype=gene_id` (to both `geom_line`s).
- Controlling the x-axis is done with `scale_x_continuous(breaks=.)`.
- I took the liberty of: adding names to your `scale_color_manual` so that the color/linetype legends would combine; adding `guides(.)` to make the legend lines thicker, just a thought, not required.
- FYI, `geom_point()` is completely masked ...

```r
Graph4_Clock |>
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("X"), names_to = "HPS", values_to = "Zscore")|>
  mutate(HPS = readr::parse_number(HPS)) |>
  ggplot(aes(x = HPS, y = Zscore, color = gene_id)) +
  # geom_point() + # doing nothing here, covered by the lines
  geom_line(aes(group=gene_id, linetype=gene_id), size = 0.5, data = ~ subset(., gene_id != "ECHO Fit")) +
  geom_line(aes(group=gene_id, linetype=gene_id), size = 0.5, data = ~ subset(., gene_id == "ECHO Fit")) +
  ggtitle("Clock") +
  scale_color_manual(values = c("Rep2" = "black", "Rep3" = "orange", "ECHO Fit" = "blue")) +
  scale_linetype_manual(values = c("Rep2" = "solid", "Rep3" = "solid", "ECHO Fit" = "longdash")) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(12, 72, by = 5)) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2))) +
  theme(
    legend.position = "bottom",
    axis.text = element_text(size = 20), axis.text.x = element_text(size = 20),
    axis.text.y = element_text(size = 20), axis.title = element_text(size = 20),
    plot.title = element_text(size = 20),
    legend.text = element_text(size = 20), legend.direction = "horizontal")
```

[image: ggplot with dashed/solid lines, one in front, fixed legends]

---

Data

```r
Graph4_Clock <- structure(list(gene_id = c("Rep2", "Rep3", "ECHO Fit"), X12 = c(0.7736722, 0.2103065, 1.0061474), X14 = c(0.4895358, -0.1527386, 0.4496992), X16 = c(-0.1152436, -0.4639241, -0.1188764), X18 = c(-0.5861007, -0.3344614, -0.548858), X20 = c(-0.5185535, 0.1491652, -0.7423424), X22 = c(-0.4028582, 0.3355411, -0.6742235), X24 = c(-0.209116905, 0.003713116, -0.39086701), X26 = c(0.043706646, -0.46645188, 0.009849424), X28 = c(-0.0558864, -0.413854, 0.4098608), X30 = c(-0.3015712, 0.2252987, 0.7041348),      X32 = c(0.06774353, 0.61276259, 0.8268523), X34 = c(0.5337989, 0.6278027, 0.7644355), X36 = c(0.7879655, 0.7112873, 0.5534309), X38 = c(0.919302, 0.5867178, 0.265452), X40 = c(-0.07623785, -0.03538973, -0.01545444), X42 = c(-0.8137335, -0.489336, -0.2162454), X44 = c(-0.5964319, -0.5010887, -0.292878), X46 = c(-0.7249979, -0.2860915, -0.2387261), X48 = c(-0.69457607, 0.04822184, -0.08225048), X50 = c(-0.32543356, -0.08333534, 0.12429807), X52 = c(-0.02661936, -0.43714633, 0.32119703), X54 = c(0.3506349,      -0.4050637, 0.4577582), X56 = c(0.4740629, -0.2733731, 0.5046638), X58 = c(0.4997113, -0.1443974, 0.4593446), X60 = c(0.73874098, 0.05656335, 0.34374438), X62 = c(0.5660296, 0.4104595, 0.1958867), X64 = c(-0.08397613, 0.45333028, 0.05813341), X66 = c(-0.23776407, 0.01404726, -0.03441813), X68 = c(0.14677824, -0.12725196, -0.06236729), X70 = c(-0.019013891, -0.000176578, -0.025399781), X72 = c(-0.55853824, 0.07900585, 0.05970666)), row.names = c("1", "2", "3"), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Reload please @yuliaUU, it's there. And it (based on the OP) _is_ completely reproducible even without the `structure(.)`, albeit needing just a little elbow grease to get it working.

Comment: can you please add your data to the question, not solution

Comment: I don't feel it's necessary. Feel free to suggest an edit to the OP (optionally using the data from this answer).